# Is this function Gateaux differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gateaux-derivative

Consider the real-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of two real variables defined by
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & \mbox{ if } (x, y)\ne (0, 0)\\
0 & \mbox{ if } (x, y)=(0, 0).
\end{cases}$$
Is this function Gateux differentiable and why? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This $f$ is $C^1$ on all of $\dot{\mathbb R}^2$, hence a fortiori Gateaux differentiable in this domain. It remains to investigate what happens at the origin. One computes
$$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x,0)-f(0,0)\over x}=1,\quad f_y(0,0)=\lim_{y\to 0}{f(0,y)-f(0,0)\over y}=0\ .$$
If $f$ were Fréchet differentiable, or just: [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) at $(0,0)$ it would therefore have to be the case that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-x\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0\ .$$
But
$${f(x,y)-f(0,0)-x\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}={r\cos^3\phi-r\cos\phi\over r}=-\sin^2\phi\cos\phi$$
does not converge to $0$ when $r\to0$. It follows that $f$ is **not** differentiable at $(0,0)$.

For [Gateaux differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative) we have to choose a *fixed* tangent vector $(u,v)$ at $(0,0)$ and to consider the limit
$$d_{(u,v)}f(0,0):=\lim_{t\to0}{f(tu,tv)-f(0,0)\over t}=\lim_{t\to0}{t^3u^3\over t(t^2u^2+t^2v^2)}={u^3\over u^2+v^2}$$
if $(u,v)\ne(0,0)$, and $=0$ otherwise. Since the limit exists for each $(u,v)$ the function $f$ is indeed Gateaux differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Is $\dot{\mathbb R}^2$ a standard notation for $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: @copper.hat: It's a notation that I often use, and its meaning is obvious in the framework of this problem. Writing $\dot U$ for a punctured neighborhood is pretty common.

Comment: Thanks! Will add it to my vocabulary.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Thanks for your answer. I think that the candidate derivative should be $$A=[f_{x}(0,0) \;\;f_{y}(0,0)]=[1\;\;0]$$ So we want $$\lim_{t\to0}{f(th_{1},th_{2})-f(0,0)-tAh\over t}\rightarrow 0$$ So $$\lim_{t\to0}{f(th_{1},th_{2})-th_{1}\over t}\rightarrow 0$$ this fails to go to 0. So the is not Gateaux differentiable. I make a mistake?

Comment: @ChrisPerv: See the linked definitions of the terms in question. Your comment refers to (Fréchet) differentiability (which has been disposed of in my answer), and not to Gateaux differentiability.

Comment: Mr @Christian Blatter the definition of gateaux which is mentioned here is not the same with the one in wikipedia link . Definition here is more strong.